# Play dailymotion videos in jwplayer

Tags: html, flash, video, jwplayer

hi im looking if you guyz can help me with this i want to play dailymotion videos with jwplayer i can play youtube videos but i also need it to play dailymotion videos please help me with this 1 
here is the code it plays youtube videos but when i put in a dailymotion url it gives me this error
"Task Queue failed at step 5: Playlist could not be loaded due to crossdomain policy restrictions."
here is the code for youtube videos that can play in jwplayer

```
<script src="swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("jwplayer").setup({
        'flashplayer': "player.swf",
        'width': '641',
        'height': '391',
        'allowfullscreen':'true',
        'allowscriptaccess':'always',
        'wmode':'opaque',
        'controlbar':'over',
        'dock':'true',
        'dock.position':'left',
        'mute':'false',
        'stretching':'uniform',
        'autostart': 'true',
        'file': 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/qBW59yz-_ZM',
        'logo.file':'logo.png',
        'logo.hide':'false',
        'logo.position':'top-right',
        'logo.link':'link',
        'abouttext':'text',
        'aboutlink':'somesite',
        'skin':'bekle.zip'
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with [this plugin](http://jwplayer.electroteque.org/dailymotion)?

Comment: i tried it but it didn't worked and i also dont want when we click on it it takes you to the site where the video is can some one help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is disappointing, but according to this thread:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/using-playlists/30409/play-dailymotion-videos-in-jwplayer/

Currently, JWplayer doesn't support 3rd party sources other than YouTube.

Update:
If you don't have to use JWplayer, you can try MediaElemnt Player http://mediaelementjs.com/ It can play both YouTube and DailyMotion videos and you only need to provide the URLs of the landing page. The dailymotion "plugin" is at https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/pull/663